# Coordinate transformation by using the differential of a function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transformation, differential, lecture-notes

As introduction to solving the one dimensional wave function our lecturer introduced us to transforming coordinates in a different way than we used to.

He elaborated the usage of the differential of a function for coordinate transformation by an example:

---

He defines the following coordinate transfomration:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
   \eta = x+y \qquad \xi = x-y
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
df = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \eta}\right)_{\xi} d\eta + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi}\right)_{\eta} d\xi
\end{equation}

He then states that (2) which is apparently just the definition of the differential of a function equals to the following:
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
 df = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \eta}\right)_{\xi} d\eta
\end{equation}
He justifies that because $d\xi=dx-dy=0$

---

We discussed that justification for an hour now and everyone got an argument that he thinks is valid but in each and every argument we found a little flaw.

We hope someone can give us the right argument for this justification.

Comment: The 1d wave equation can be expressed in different ways. How did your lecturer specify it? Are there boundary conditions that may be relavent?

Comment: He defined it as $$ \partial^2 u\over \partial t^2 } = c^2 { \partial^2 u\over \partial  x^2 $$ . However this example had in its essence nothing to do with the wave equation but rather was there to display the principle of coordinate transformation with the differential of a function

Comment: The usual process is a coordinate transform to x-ct and x+ct. Incidentally where did y come from?

Comment: Yes I know. A few lines later he applies the same principle to the solutions of the one-dimensional wave equation just as you pointed out. It seems as though he just wants to get the principle started by an easier example. I am afraid I don't understand the question "where did y come from".

Comment: In general, it's not true. There can be reason due to causality (hence why I asked about boundary conditions) which would only allow solutions propagating forward in time that could be an argument.

Comment: You have expressed things originally in x,y rather than x,t

Comment: Hmm. I see. Sadly there aren't any boundary conditions. In fact the equations I posted is everything we got. Later on however he mentions that we have the example of $f(x,y)=y$ . Maybe he used that retroactive. However I don't see how that could make things better...

Answer (score 1):

Unless your x and y mean something special, that final statement is not valid.
From discussion in the comments, all I can think of is causality, but without boundary conditions on which it could be based, it can't be justified and in no way is true in general.
Go back to your levturer. The onus is on them to explain things clearly.

Comment: We don't have any additional information. This is really confusing. Is there any chance that one can find a justification the makes (2) = (3)? Because otherwise this would be just terribly wrong

Comment: Way ahead of you, but I fail to see how you can claim "there is no justification" is not an answer.